# Exclude property from persistence in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an array for mapping properties in my PHP model:

`/**
 * @var array
 */
 protected $mapping = array('q' => 'query', 's' => 'start');`

I want to exclude this property from being persisted by Doctrine, but I found no proper annotation for it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: just don't add any doctrine annotations in the first place and you are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to not include the PHPDoc:

`protected $mapping = array('q' => 'query', 's' => 'start');`